# Weird electrical buzzing noise from psu

Tags: power-supply

https://youtu.be/GgN5kLD1YdI

It's the buzzing noise, is it normal?

Answer (score 0):

No, not normal, but not necessarily harmful. It is likely the toroid coil in the supply which is a bit loose and therefore buzzes. You may wish to replace the power supply in due course

Comment: But for right now it should be fine?

Comment: Yes, it should be fine for a while as the noise is just the low frequency hum of the coil.